# How can I limit the number of significant digits in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, format, limit

I need to have Value of a field to be either something like "12345678" (At mots 8 digits) or "12345678.1234" (8 significant digits and 4 digits after the decimal point). These digits are checked at the time when user actually enters them. It depends on the user what he enters. But he must not exceed the limit

I tried format-number function, But It doesn't work.
PS: My employer wouldn't let me copy-paste code here.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks,
Aashiq Hussain.

Comment: If you can't share your code, might you at least tell us in what way `format-number()` didn't work? To people trying to give technical help an unclarified, "it didn't work" is more unpleasant than a curse word.

Comment: It is first time I am encountering XSL. I was expecting format-number(., "00000000.0000") to work like "12345678.1234". But I think, it is not this function is supposed to do.
In Nutshell, I need any other way to do what I want to do. :)

Comment: Again, how was `format-number` different from your expectations?  It will truncate the decimal portion but not the whole number portion (because that usually wouldn't be a sensible thing to do).  Are you saying that if you had the value 1234567890.1234567, you would want the result to be 34567890.1234?

Comment: I don't want let user to enter any more digits after 12345678. He can only if He enters a point and then 1234 (again he should not be able to go beyond 4). That is, Either only 8-digits or 8-digits before point plus 4-digits after point. It is kinda you have those onkeypress events in js. But I want similar to that in XSLT.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't make much sense. XSLT converts XML input into XML output. It cannot impose control over user interaction. If you are using the XSLT to generate HTML that the user will see, then the HTML you generate should do the input validation, not the XSLT.

Comment: "My employer wouldn't let me copy-paste code here." It's not unusual for businesses to treat participation in the community as a one-way street - we want your help, but we won't share anything in return - but it's unusual to be quite so open about it - If that's a word I can use.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to truncate anything that exceeds 8 digits before the decimal point, or that exceeds 4 after the decimal point?  How about this?

```
format-number(. mod 100000000, '#.####')
```

Comment: in deed this is the better solution

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="x">
  <xsl:variable name="vIntPart" select="floor(.)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vFractPart" select=". - $vIntPart"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($vIntPart, 1,8),
                               '.',
                               substring($vFractPart*10000, 1,4)
                               )"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
 <x>1234567890.9876543</x>
 <x>1234567890</x>
 <x>.9876543</x>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
 12345678.9876
 12345678.0
 0.9876
```